# How to detect if a variable has changed in python with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, variables, selenium-chromedriver

I have built a python script with selenium that checks a certain website for a number. Whenever I run the script it returns the updated number from that website and puts it in a variable. But how can I detect when the variables value has changed and how to print something when it has changed?

Comment: Create a prev variable and compare it with current number returned.

Answer (score 0):

Could have another variable like `prevVar` and do something along the lines of

```py
prevVar = 0
watchVar = 0

while True:
    # Do stuff that updates watchVar
    if prevVar != watchVar:
        print("Value has updated to something different")
        # Update prevVar to the new watchVar
        prevVar = watchVar
```

Just using a second variable to track the previous variable's value.

Edit: This is also based on the assumption you mean a local value and not the variable from the site being checked with selenium.

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447397/how-to-check-if-a-variables-value-has-changed)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still a beginner so I have a lot to learn...