# @property like syntax - but without declaring the property or variable inside a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking for a way to achieve the following syntax:

```py
import myModule
myModule.myString = "Foo"
```

and be able to control *how* and *where* the actual data is stored & retrieved behind the scenes - ideally I would just have getter/setter functions that gets called when I try accessing any of the values in `myModule`.

---

##### Solutions that Ive thought of, but that doesnt quite fit the bill

###### property

`@property` as already described, properties seem to require a class - which would make the syntax for accessing the properties of my module `myModule.classInstanceName.myString` when I really just want `moduleName.myString` . If there is a way of somehow exposing a property on the class instance in a way where I wouldnt have to access it through the class instance, that would be a feasible workaround.

###### magic methods that I really wish existed (heh)

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, cb):
        self.cb = cb
    def __get_self__(self): # Psuedo code, theres no magic method like this, is there?
        return self.cb()
    def __set_self__(self, val): # Psuedo code, theres no magic method like this, is there?
        hi = val
        return self.cb()
hi = "yo"
myClsInstance = MyClass(lambda: return hi, hi)
print(myClsInstance) # Prints "yo"
```

###### Polling for changes

I guess another solution would be to just constantly check if any of my variables have been modified and run some code to correct there values as desired. Thought, at this point I feel just exposing raw functions as setter/getters would probably be better.
[How to check if a variable's value has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447397/how-to-check-if-a-variables-value-has-changed)

#### `__str__`

I guess what concerns me most about this is that I would have to excplicitly convert to string every time I try accessing the value - and I would be limited to variable types that has associated magic methods like this one.

---

Any thoughtss or insights would be appreciated  It looks like Blenders BPY API managed to achieve it somehow with the content located under `bpy.data` - though, not sure how they did it.

Comment: Not what you intended, but `print` is going to implicitly call `str(myClsInstance)`, so the method you are looking for is `__str__`. Otherwise, no, you can't hack straight name lookup in this way.

Comment: it really isn't clear to me what the semantics you are asking for entail.

Comment: @Mous is there any particular feature of the meta class that you we're thinking of? Its not quite clear to me how they could be useful in this case

Comment: `__getattribute__` still involves, well, an attribute, which is not in use when you are simply resolving a *name* like `myClsInstance`. There is no such hook in Python. Names are fundamental.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `bpy.data` isn't anything particularly special, and it certainly doesn't do the thing you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What aspect of `bpy.data`'s behavior are you trying to replicate? Can you show a code sample for something you can do with `bpy.data` that led you to believe Blender is doing something like what you're asking about?

Comment: @user2357112 Bpy was just an example that came to mind as I was writing & Im not sure how much it would help describe what Im trying to do (I will modify the question to see if I can clarify it) and its perfectly possible they are using dynamic code generation to achieve what they're doing.

But BPY is Blenders python library, some portions of it lets you set values like `myData = "someValue"` and see resulting changes in the renderer. So somehow they can detect when youre setting a variable similarily to `@property` - which is essentially what Im trying to do.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything like that in the Blender Python API documentation.

Comment: OK, with the *significant* change you've made to the question, it's theoretically possible to make `myModule.myString` a descriptor. However, that would involve patching `types.ModuleType` (which you can't do) or implementing a custom module loader to define what `import myModule` really means here.