# Python detect changing (global) variable

Tags: python

To make a somewhat long explanation rather simple for someone who's not fully into my project as me; I'm trying to find a way to detect a global variables that change in Python 2.7.

I'm trying to send updated to another device who registers them.

To reduce traffic and CPU load, instead of opting for a periodic update message, I was thinking of only sending an update message when a variable changes, and I might be tired right now but I don't know how I can detect a variable that changes.

Is there a library or something I can take advantage of?

Thank you!

Comment: There should only be a finite number of places which change the variable. Create a function which makes a change to the variable and at the same time sends the update. Make every place that wants to change the variable call that function instead. *Encapsulation* is the keyword here.

Comment: Change the name of the variable too so you get an error for anythign not going through the new function

Comment: This answer has some clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540443/detecting-change-in-the-value-of-python-variables and mentions a notify package: http://download.gna.org/py-notify/reference/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Pub/Sub feature of Redis if this kind of behaviour is typical in your codebase. https://redis.io/topics/pubsub. 
 Every time your variable changes, you publish this event on a channel. 
For example let's call the channel *variableUpdates*. 
The devices that depend on your variable value subscribe to the channel *variableUpdates*. 
Every time when your variable changes you publish this event on the channel *variableUpdates*. 
When this happens, your listeners get notified of this event, read the new variable value and use it in their own context.